# Dynamically read value of html input field: python

Tags: python, browser, html, input-field

I have an external browser plugin (which is blackbox to me). This plugin tries to fill values to input fields of html page (on load. I want to make a program, which is able if the external program filled values properly.

So what I want to do is to open an url from my python program in a browser. On load of this page is automatically executed the plugin and tries to insert values. After that I want to find specific input fields and resolve, whether they are filled correctly or not in the current instance of the browser and page.

Is there any way to do such thing using python (standard or 3rd party) modules? Could you recommend me any?

(Note: I also want to build exe file using cx_freeze, so the best would be, if the module does not depend on external files)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [`PyQt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060439/filling-out-a-form-using-pyqt-and-qwebview) or [`Selenium`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: PyQt can access the browser the way I need? And if I understand properly, selenium requires extra "Server" file to communicate with, wouldn't it be a problem, when build with cx_freeze?

Comment: I haven't used Selenium, but i worked with PyQt. You open a web page in a widget, load a URL in it, then you can access the DOM and execute Javascript on the page.